# Using an input string in a textbox

Tags: java, input

I am trying to have the user input a number, and then that number is used to populate 
a text field on a jform.  However it keeps giving me errors.  If I have the textfield call the str it gives me a numberformatexception, if I have it call the int variable it says it has to be a string...

```
public static String prePaidstr = "";
public static double prePaidint = 0;

prePaidstr = 
JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter any amount prepaid:");
prePaidint = Double.parseDouble(prePaidstr);

jTextField13.setText(InvoiceSelectionUI.prePaidstr)
```

Comment: It would help if you can publish the exception(s) thrown with their data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parseDouble` converts a `String` into a `Double`, which is why it complains if you try to pass it a `double`.

A NumberFormatException is thrown when `parseDouble` is unable to successfully turn a String into a double; in this case it's because you're trying to `parseDouble` on an empty string. `prePaidStr` needs to contain something like `"1.99"` - e.g. something that, to a human, looks like a `Double`.

Answer (score 0):

nm - I fixed it, just had one of the variables switched around

Comment: Then mark the question as answered so people don't waste time reading the question.

Comment: If the question is no longer relevant, you can close it instead.